# Cannot deploy kivy app with RstDocument

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, restructuredtext

I have a problem deploying a Kivy application using RstDocument. It works fine on PC. I can deploy it if I use Label instead of RstDocument, but it stops in the latter case.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

import configparser

class MainFrame(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

    def on_quit_button_click(self):
        quit()


class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainFrame()
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BasicApp().run()
```

with the following basic.kv

```
<MainFrame>:
    BoxLayout:
        RstDocument:
        #Label:
            text: 'Hello *world*!'
        Button:
            text: 'Click to quit'
            on_press: root.on_quit_button_click()
```

Nothing significant in logcat, just

```
 WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{bf4383ed0 u0 Application Error: testrstdocument.testrstdocument} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Buildozer.spec

I am able to run a Kivy App with *rstDocument* on an Acer Android tablet by adding ***docutils*** into buildozer's requirement.

```
requirements = kivy, configparser, docutils
```

Comment: Thank you.Never thought about requirements. Is there relevant documentation that I missed?

Comment: There isn't any relevant documentation on this and you didn't miss it.